# Estimated gas is always low

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, ethereumjs

web3.eth.estimateGas is always calculating low gas for the transaction. Here is a reference to a trasaction in ropsten. 
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xd5bead5b576b2f4e4cbe83e4acf20d701740b05fdaf3f2749e0c1973ea4c7d6c

I used the data feild and contract address to calculate the gas. I got => 21464. But it actaully required 47032. 
This is one example but I have the same problem for other transactions as well.

`web3.eth.estimateGas({
    to: "0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe",
    data: "0xc6888fa10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003"
})
.then(console.log);`

Comment: does this call removes any storage on the StateDB ? if so, this is the reason. Check this explanation: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56287/if-metamask-gas-calculations-are-nearly-perfect-why-do-we-still-get-out-of-gas-e/56444#56444

Answer (score 0):

yes.but not always lower, we just can say it's not accurate, due to the time flying and the ETH network change every second.

This estimation is based on the right now state of the network when you check.

However, the actual gas required for a transaction is depending on a number of factors such as the complexity of the transaction and the current state of the network.