# how accurate are gas estimates?

Tags: solidity, web3js, transactions, gas-limit, require

I am currently running some tests on ganache using web3.js connector.

Most of my transactions run OK if I supply the same amount of gas that is suggested by web3.eth.estimateGas(), however, one of the transactions uses about 3x the gas estimate provided by web3.eth.estimateGas(....), is this normal??

My concern is that once I deploy this on the mainnet and if this recurs randomly then I could be out of a lot of gas due to aborted operations resulting from inadequate gas supplied for the transaction.

What is the best practice for handling this kind of situation, should I normally supply x times the gasEstimate just to be on the safe side...what is a good value for x.

as a side note, the function call in question has three require statements, does that impact gas consumption in a big way??

Comment: does this transaction that uses 3x gas free some storage?

Comment: no, it adds a small amount of storage (2 x strings < 64 bytes + 1 x uint32

Comment: if the execution path is constant and you are 100% sure your contract isn't releasing any storage (that is setting some storage to 0) , estimateGas() should give accurate estimation. It is only wrong when you release storage. Every release of storage gives you +15000 more gas requirement, so if you clean some set of data in a loop, that's going to cost a lot in gas, an `estimateGas()` has no way of knowing it

Comment: What are the values are you talking about? 1M -> 3M or 40k -> 120k. Estimation is done executing the transaction and discarding the changes. I've seen transfers of the same ERC20 tokens vary from 40k to around 100k.

Comment: @Nulik: From my experience, it is wrong also when your function calls a function in another contract.

Comment: @goodvibration only if this function in another contract releases storage. Check that contract opcodes for `SSTORE` , if it has it and it happens that it releases storage, then that's the reason. There are only 2 instructions that release gas , suicide and storage release. In all other cases `estimateGas()` will give you correct estimation because it runs the contract with a `Call()` and takes the `gaseUsed` variable from the output of the `Call()`, it can't make a wrong estimate in this case.

Comment: if you want to always have a correct gas estimation you have to patch `geth` like I am explaining here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56287/if-metamask-gas-calculations-are-nearly-perfect-why-do-we-still-get-out-of-gas-e/56444#56444

Answer (score 2):

Gas estimations are generally correct but sometimes gas used is very high as compared to gas estimation which depends on output too. If your transaction is successful gas used is low but when it fails gas used is high as it uses some searching algorithms.

For the safe side you can increase gas limit and gas price.
I use GasPrice = 5000000 wei and GasLimit = 2000000000 wei. Works well for me.