# Deciding Gas Pricing

Tags: metamask, gas, gas-limit, gas-price, gas-estimate

Anyone know how curve fi and metamask fetch the average gas price for the transaction and how they provide the slow and fast option? I just want to know which third party they use to get these info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the answer in following [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56287/if-metamask-gas-calculations-are-nearly-perfect-why-do-we-still-get-out-of-gas-e)

It seems like they use a binary search to calculate estimated gas based on the opcodes.

Comment: The link is about estimating the gas limit, not the gas price.

Comment: I was asking about gas price not limit, I know we can get it using web3 also but I guess web3 only give the average price so I just want to know how they give the fast and slow option